# changing the logic symbols in lplfitch.sty

Tags: logic

I'm using lplfitch.sty to produce Fitch-style natural deduction proofs.  I want to use different symbols from the ones that are predefined.  Specifically, I want to use \sim instead of \neg for negation, and \supset instead of \rightarrow for the conditional.  How can I change these?

Answer (score 3):

The command you don't like is defined with a simple `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand*\lif{\rightarrow}
```

Just modify it definitions to suit your tastes:

```
\renewcommand*\lif{\supset}
```

You'll next want to redefine `\lnot`:

```
\renewcommand*\lnot{\mathord{\sim}}
```

(note that `\mathord` is necessary as `\sim` is considered a binary relation symbol otherwise).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lplfitch}

\renewcommand*\lif{\supset}
\renewcommand*\lnot{\mathord{\sim}}

\begin{document}

$\uni{x}{\exi{y}{(P(x)\lif \lnot Q(x,y))}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]